# what is the numerical method to guarantee safer matrix inversion?

Tags: matrix, numerical-methods, inversion

I am trying to develop an algorithm (in the framework of gradient descent )for an SEM(structural equation model) problem.There is a parameter matrix B(n*n) with all its diagonal elements fixed to be zero.And a term of inv(I-B) (inversion of I - B) in my objective function.There is no other constraint such as symmetry on B.

My question is that how can we make sure (I-B) is not singular in the iterations?

In this problem,because the domain of the objective function is not the whole R^n space,it seems that the strict conditions for the convergence of gradient descent will be not satisfied.Standard textbooks will assume the objective to have a domain in the whole R^n space.It seems that gradient descent will not have a guaranteed convergence.

In the update of the iterative algorithms,currently my implementation is that checking whether (I-B) is close to singular, then if it is not, the step size of the gradient descent will be shrunk.Is there any better numerical approach to dealing with this problem?

Comment: You already checked the simple variants, such as ||B||<1 in any sub-multiplicative matrix norm?

Comment: B is determined by the data and no prior information is available.

Comment: I would do a simple LU-decomposition and check if the diagonal has a zero or not. Having the LU decomposition allows you to compute directly the inverse from there. Also, are you sure you need the inverse? Most of the times you never actually need to compute it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try putting a logarithmic barrier on `det(I-B)>0`  or `det(I-B)<0` depending on which gives you a better result, or if you have more info about your problem . the gradient of `logdet` is quite nice https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38701/how-to-calculate-the-gradient-of-log-det-matrix-inverse

You can also compute the Fenchel dual so you can potentially use a primal-dual approach.